# activerecord - query through attributes of related record

Tags: activerecord

```
class Book
  belongs_to :library
end

class Library
  belongs_to :city
  has_many :books
end

class City
  has_many :libraries
  has_many :books, through: :library
end
```

I want to be able to query

```
Book.where("library.city.name = ?", "Alexandria")
```

How do I correctly do this with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 0):

Your `city` model already has many books through libraries, so I believe

```
City.find_by(name: "Alexandria").books
```

should do the trick

Comment: holy moly, this is a very old question, anyways i'll leave the answer there in case someone stumbles across this